# Join row of dataframe with previous row if condition do not match

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as shown below:

## df

```
data
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'abcdef', 'date': '2017-04-14', 'serialNo': '215687'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'abcdef', 'date': '2017-04-16', 'serialNo': '456123'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'abcdef', 'date': '2017-04-17'
, 'serialNo': '456125'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'qwerty', 'date': '2017-04-20', 'serialNo': '456166'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'qwerty', 'date': '2017-04-21', 'seri
alNo': '756984'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'zxcvbn', 'date': '2017-04-24', 'serialNo': '852369'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'zxcvbn', 'date': '2017-04-26', 'serialNo': '852367'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'zaqwsx', 
'date': '2017-04-27', 'serialNo': '854123'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'edcvfr'
, 'date': '2017-04-28', 'serialNo': '852369'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'yuiopa', 'date': '2017-04-29', 'serialNo': '523698'}]
```

What I want is, If row doesn't start with specific string (here in my case it is "10.100.10.10==>") it should be joined with previous row. Here in example row 4 is not starting with "10.100.10.10==>" so it is joined with row 3. Same as for row 7, 11 and 13.

```
data
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'abcdef', 'date': '2017-04-14', 'serialNo': '215687'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'abcdef', 'date': '2017-04-16', 'serialNo': '456123'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'abcdef', 'date': '2017-04-17', 'serialNo': '456125'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'qwerty', 'date': '2017-04-20', 'serialNo': '456166'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'qwerty', 'date': '2017-04-21', 'serialNo': '756984'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'zxcvbn', 'date': '2017-04-24', 'serialNo': '852369'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'zxcvbn', 'date': '2017-04-26', 'serialNo': '852367'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'zaqwsx', 'date': '2017-04-27', 'serialNo': '854123'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'edcvfr', 'date': '2017-04-28', 'serialNo': '852369'}]
10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'yuiopa', 'date': '2017-04-29', 'serialNo': '523698'}]
```

I was able to do it with below code but i am having huge dataset and it is taking long time.

```
for i in range(0,len(df["Data"])):
    if df['Data'][i].startswith("10.100.10.10==>"):
        df['Data'][i] = df['Data'][i]
    else:
        df['Data'][i-1] = "".join([df['Data'][i-1],df['Data'][i]])
df = df[df['Data'].str.startswith("10.100.10.10==>")].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Please let me know if there is any other faster way to complete this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
marker = '10.100.10.10==>'
groups = df.Data.str.startswith(marker).cumsum()
df.Data.groupby(groups).sum()

0
1     10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'abcdef', 'date': '201...
2     10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'abcdef', 'date': '201...
3     10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'abcdef', 'date': '201...
4     10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'qwerty', 'date': '201...
5     10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'qwerty', 'date': '201...
6     10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'zxcvbn', 'date': '201...
7     10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'zxcvbn', 'date': '201...
8     10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'zaqwsx', 'date': '201...
9     10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'edcvfr', 'date': '201...
10    10.100.10.10==> [{'ID': 'yuiopa', 'date': '201...
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you @piRSquared. This works exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Pandas for this.  Just read the file a line at a time, and build a list of lines.  Then you can load that list of corrected lines into Pandas.  You do not need fancy join or anything else--just build a list, and append to the previous item when the next line doesn't start with what you expect.

If you want, you can split each line on `==>` and load the first part into a Pandas Series and the rest into a DataFrame.  `pd.io.json.json_normalize()` may help for that last part.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @John.